# Syntax error or access violation: 1064:syntax to use near 'unsigned not null, modelName varchar(191) not null, title varchar(191) not n

Tags: php, database, phpmyadmin, migration, laravel-5.4

Everything was working fine till I started using `users` tables id as a foreign key in `blogs` table and tried to migrate it into the database. I started getting errors of

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right synt
>     ax to use near 'unsigned not null, `modelName` varchar(191) not null, `title` varchar(191) not n' at line 1 (SQL: create table `blogs` (`id` int unsigned not null auto_increment
>      primary key, `user_id` varchar(191) unsigned not null, `modelName` varchar(191) not null, `title` varchar(191) not null, `price` int unsigned not null, `description` text not n
>     ull, `status` int not null, `photo_id` varchar(191) not null, `company_id` varchar(191) not null default '1', `created_at` timestamp null, `updated_at` timestamp null) default c
>     haracter set utf8mb4 collate utf8mb4_unicode_ci)
>   In Connection.php line 445:
>     SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right synt
>     ax to use near 'unsigned not null, `modelName` varchar(191) not null, `title` varchar(191) not n' at line 1**

here is the users table structure

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('role_id')->index()->unsigned()->nullable();
            $table->integer('is_active')->default(0);
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('photo_id')->default('default.png');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

and here's the blogs table structure

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('blogs', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('modelName')->index();
            $table->string('title');
            $table->integer('price')->unsigned();
            $table->text('description')->nullable(false);
            $table->integer('status');
            $table->string('photo_id');
            $table->string('company_id')->default(!null);
            $table->timestamps();

//            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->refrences('id')->on('users');

        });
    }
```

I have tried almost everything in my knowledge that could be going wrong and also tried solutions available online, but nothing seems to be working right now. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$table->string('user_id')->unsigned();`

Fields of type `string` cannot be unsigned. Change to

`$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();`

Comment: thanks for the correction :) 
that happens when you code for eight hours straight :D

Comment: but now i'm getting
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right synt
  ax to use near ')' at line 1 (SQL: alter table `blogs` add constraint `blogs_user_id_foreign` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` ())


In Connection.php line 445:

  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right synt
  ax to use near ')' at line 1

Comment: It's `references`, not `refrences`. Get some sleep ;) (And maybe accept this answer)

Comment: actually i had 2 more tables comments and comments_reply both were using blog_id and comment_id as foreign respectively and i checked there for the spellings and they were correct so i didn't checked f :Dor it there cause i was copy pasting all the time.

Comment: Thanks @kerbholz for the help and suggestion :) 
now i definitely going to get some rest :D

Comment: $table->integer('user_id'); if fine, cose the project never pass unsigned value

Comment: @MHFuad Unsigned integers have a higher max value though, max signed is 2147483647, max unsigned is 4294967295